# Outputting Invoke-WebRequest to a logfile with datetime (oneliner for task scheduler)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a process that needs to be reviewed in case of failure so I need to log the web content to a file but I'm fighting the Powershell syntax. The following line is what I attempted to write in the task scheduler as :

powershell.exe -noexit -Command "Invoke-WebRequest http://google.com -outfile C:\Users\user_gc$(get-date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm').txt"

Usually powershell or Invoke-WebREquest complains about the get-date command. "The given path format is not supported"

It's very important to me that the date and time are in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:` in the date format makes the path invalid (and the space may cause you problems down the line too). Try `'yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm'` or some other "safe" format uses filesystem safe characters that suits you.

See [Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) specifically:

> Use any character in the current code page ... except for the following reserved characters:
>
> - < (less than)
> - > (greater than)
> - : (colon)
> - " (double quote)
> - / (forward slash)
> - \ (backslash)
> - | (vertical bar or pipe)
> - ? (question mark)
> - - (asterisk)

You can trigger the same error by trying to create a file with a similar name and it will throw an error:

```
PS c:\temp> new-item -ItemType File -Path ".\2023-01-05 19:51.txt" -Value "is this file created?"
new-item : The given path's format is not supported.
At line:1 char:1
+ new-item -ItemType File -Path ".\2023-01-05 19:51.txt" -Value "is thi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Item], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Answer (score 2):

### Script

Save below in script file `TaskName.ps1` Make sure to change the variables to your needs

```
# Enter Your Path
$path = 'C:\Temp\'

# Enter Website You Want To Reach
$uri = 'https://google.com'

# For File Name
$timeStamp = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HHmm')

# Regex To Remove https://
$webSite = $uri -replace '^.+?(//)', '$`'

# Test If $path is Valid. If not, Create $path
switch (Test-Path $path) {
    'false' { mkdir -Path $path }
    Default { continue }
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri |
    Out-File -FilePath "$path$webSite $timeStamp.txt" -Force
```

### Task Scheduler

Action: `Start a program`

Settings:
Program/Script: `Powershell.exe`
Add arguments (optional):
`-windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass -File "C:\temp\TaskScheduler.ps1"`
**Note:** This will require admin privileges

### Results

File Name:
`"C:\temp\google.com 2023-01-05 1341.txt"`